# How to save a JPEG image on Android with a custom quality level

Tags: java, android, jpeg, lossy-compression

On Android, how do I save an image file as a JPEG at 30% quality?

In standard Java, I would use `ImageIO` to read the image as a `BufferedImage`, then save it as a JPEG file using an `IIOImage` instance: http://www.universalwebservices.net/web-programming-resources/java/adjust-jpeg-image-compression-quality-when-saving-images-in-java. It appears, however, that Android lacks the `javax.imageio` package.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can store your bitmap in the JPEG format by calling compress and setting the second parameter:

```
    Bitmap bm2 = createBitmap();
    OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test.jpg");
    /* Write bitmap to file using JPEG and 80% quality hint for JPEG. */
    bm2.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
```

Comment: Is that `.../test.png` a typo then?

Answer (score 4):

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
try {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    File tmpFile = //...;
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
        try {
            if (bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, out)) {
                { File tmp = file; file = tmpFile; tmpFile = tmp; }
                tmpFile.delete();
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Failed to save the image as a JPEG");
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        tmpFile.delete();
        throw t;
    }
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Phyrum Tea is good only do not forget close everything

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(context.getFilesDir() + "image.jpg");
Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(
        context.getFilesDir() + pathImage + "/" + idPicture + ".jpg"));
bm2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
stream.close();
in.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Kotlin to save a file in `path` to `tmpPath`:

```
Files.newInputStream(path).use { inputStream ->
    Files.newOutputStream(tmpPath).use { tmpOutputStream ->
        BitmapFactory
            .decodeStream(inputStream)
            .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, tmpOutputStream)
    }
}
```

Edit: make sure you check for the possibility of the decode failing (and returning null) and also that compress actually worked (boolean return type).

```
    val success: Boolean = Files.newInputStream(path).use { inputStream ->
        Files.newOutputStream(tmpPath).use { tmpOutputStream ->
            BitmapFactory
                .decodeStream(inputStream)
                ?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, config.qualityLevel, tmpOutputStream)
                ?: throw Exception("Failed to decode image")
        }
    }

    if (!success) {
        throw Exception("Failed to compress and save image")
    }
```